# Mockito Test for Elastic Java api client

Tags: java, elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient, elasticsearch-high-level-restclient

I have tried to mock the response for the below method, but it's not working. Not able to mock the search.hits().hits() method.

Any idea how to do that?

```
SearchResponse<Product> search = client.search(s -> s
    .index("products")
    .query(q -> q
        .term(t -> t
            .field("name")
            .value(v -> v.stringValue("bicycle"))
        )),
    Product.class);

for (Hit<Product> hit: search.hits().hits()) {
    processProduct(hit.source());
}
```

Reference for code- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/connecting.html#_your_first_request

Comment: let me guess: You tried to mock a "chained call" like: `when(someMock.hits().hits()).then...`? No, though this is legal syntax&runtime, it won't give you the desired result, you have to : `when(someMock.hits()).then...` pass some (real or mock) object/class... and when this is again a mock, you have to `when(someOtherMock.hits()).then...`

Comment: Hit hit = mock(Hit.class);
        HitsMetadata hitsMetadata = mock(HitsMetadata.class);
        when(searchResponse.hits()).thenReturn(hitsMetadata);
        when(hit.source()).thenReturn(mockContent(Collections.singletonList("ScaledImage"),1));
        when(hitsMetadata.hits()).thenReturn(List.of(hit));
        Mockito.when(elasticClient.search((SearchRequest) Mockito.any(),
                        Mockito.any()))
                .thenReturn(searchResponse);

Comment: i tried this but its not working

Comment: Can you check [this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-java/blob/main/java-client/src/test/java/co/elastic/clients/documentation/usage/SearchingTest.java) code. it might help you to writing junit.